# Mac process identification

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

When I look at all the processes running on Mac, I see a ton of them I have no idea what they are. Occasionally I google a few and find answers on the web.

However, I was thinking, it would be really nice to have a tool similar to Little Snitch - but instead of network watching, it would instead monitor running processes. Even better if it had a common database of known processes (ie. ones from Apple, things like Chrome, etc) and maybe flagged in yellow ones that were unknown to which I could then add my own notes if it was a process I knew about. In this way, after a short period of time, much like Little Snitch, I'd have identified all the usual processes on my machine and be able to track new ones that pop up that I might want to research.

In all my Google searching, I'm unable to find anything that does this. Anyone know of something that I'm missing that comes close to what I'm looking for?

Comment: This is typically what virus scanning software does as part of its active monitoring. But I’ve not seen anything either in my travels.